# How can I assign separate stylesheets to different pages?

Tags: php, theme-development, functions, themes

I am trying to figure out how to assign a seperate stylesheet for different pages? I wan't to use the same stylesheet for my front page, and page template and a different stylesheet for my blog and it's related pages.

My theme only consists of a front page, a page template and a blog. So I would somehow need to figure out how to differentiate from the actual pages. It would need to be applied to all blog pages.

So I am wondering if I could do something like this(added to the header):

```
<?php if ( 'front-page.php' ) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } elseif ( 'page.php' ) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"  type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } else { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"  type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <?php } ?>
```

If it is front page or the page template it uses the normal stylesheet. If it is anything else, it uses the blog stylesheet. If it can be done like that, can anyone help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method is to *enqueue* the stylesheets, via callback hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts`. You can add the contextual conditionals inside the callback:

```
function wpse124258_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {    
        // Conditionally enqueue
        if ( is_front_page() ) {
            // Front page stylesheet
            wp_enqueue_style( 'front-page-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/front-page-stylesheet.css' );
        } else if ( is_page() ) {
            // Static page style
            wp_enqueue_style( 'static-page-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/front-page-stylesheet.css' );
        } else {
            // Default style
            wp_enqueue_style( 'default-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse124258_enqueue_scripts' );
```

For more information, refer to the Codex for [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Comment: `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` is not fired in backend, so checking for `! is_admin()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, yeah; it's `wp_print_*` that fire in both places.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), especially [`is_front_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page), [`is_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) or [`is_page_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)

Your code should probably look like:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"type="text/css" media="screen" /><?php 
} elseif ( is_page() ) { ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"  type="text/css" media="screen" /><?php 
} else { ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"  type="text/css" media="screen" /><?php 
}
```

Though if you want to target a particular template you can use `is_page_template`:

```
if (is_page_template('some-template.php')) {
```

Comment: Scripts and stylesheets should always be *enqueued* rather than hard-coded in the document head. Also, use `get_stylesheet_uri()` in place of `get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' )`.

Comment: @chipbennett is correct. You should be enqueueing the scripts